# How to get Audio Drivers for Macbook in Windows 10

Tags: audio, bootcamp, windows, driver

I have installed Windows 10 on my Mid 2012 Macbook Pro. I already had a separate partition which was a leftover from Ubuntu in it, so I didn't partitioned it using Bootcamp and directly formatted it in NTFS. I then used Bootcamp assistant which automatically detected the NTFS partition.
I made a bootable usb and installed Windows 10 using it. It does have latest drivers too. Everything is working in it after installing Bootcamp drivers except the sound. I just get a red cross on the Volume icon in system tray and when I click on it, Windows starts to troubleshoot and the result always points that the hardware change might not have detected and it's been fixed now.

However it never gets fixed. In device manager, I get a yellow warning mark under High Definition audio controller and no other audio device. I have tried installing both Realtek and Cirrus drivers, but they doesn't get installed saying that they are incompatible.

How can I get the audio to work in Windows 10?

Comment: Quite likely that you can't, until Apple updates its BootCamp drivers to support Windows 10. If that's the only thing that's not working you've done a lot better than me :)

Comment: @scottishwildcat I'm sure others got successful in  getting all the drivers installed properly. How come there's driver issues on one MacBook while  another one doesn't get any issues? Anyways will wait for the updates. Leaving the question open in case someone have better answer.

Comment: @noob There are issues on one Macbook and not another simply because different models of Macbook have different hardware, or different revisions of the same hardware. Graphics cards, sound chips, USB buses, ethernet controllers etc. can all vary between models, and Windows will sometimes need different drivers for some of those variants.

Comment: If you are still having problems, try this: 1) Use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Boot Camp Software. 2) Do a clean install of Windows 10 **without** being connected to the internet. 3) Install the Boot Camp Software 4) Check the Device Manager for errors

Comment: Same here , MBP 2012 , 8 GIG RAM + 2TB HDD replaced instead the stock 4 GIG RAM and 500 GIG HDD and using Bootcamp 6.0 , no audio.

Comment: I am searching for Drivers for Audio also: I use 2 Cinema Displays on a non-Mac PC with Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Apple just released the [Bootcamp 6 for Windows 10](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990).

Check in this article if your Model qualifies and how to do it.

Comment: I used Apple Software update app to update the Bootcamp utility to the latest version. My macbook is Mid 2012, thus the update was available for it.However it didn't solve the audio issue. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: No audio here, MBP 2012. I am using USB port to get audio in Windows 10. The rest is fine, I tested Steam games (Alan Wake).